# git master branch should be synched with which environment...?

Tags: git, git-branch

**Current Process Flow :**

Currently i am having four Git branches ***`master`, `prod`, `stage` and `dev`***.

The commit goes in this order:

- all the development commits goes to the `dev` branch at the end of each sprint or ticket all the `dev` commits will be manually merged to a `release` branch by the respective developers and given as a single commit revision.
- The `release` team will take the single change-set done at the release branch for releasing the story to stage for Q.A (No test environment is created for Q.A till now)
- And finally, during the releases, the `stage` and `prod` will be merged and a unique tag is created and deployed in the production.

**Issue :**

Currently the `master` is synced with the `stage` environment but since we do not have a test environment Q.A is done at this branch and the branch is not a stable one.

I really need to know :  The `master` should be synced up with which environment (`dev`, `stage` or `prod`)..?

Please help me on this.

Comment: Maybe this link about a successful branching setup may help you: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: Branching per environment is a continuous delivery anti-pattern. Ideally, you have a single branch that represents a deployable version of your software, and you build, test, and deploy that version through your series of environments via automation. The GitFlow and GitHubFlow patterns mentioned in the comment above are excellent starting points.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally:

- `master` (2014) or these days ([2020+](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-the-default-branch-for-newly-created-repositories-is-now-main/)) `main` should always representing production ie no need for `prod`.
- (pre-)release branch (or "stage") is a good place for the staging process (where you integrates commits that are eligible to go to the next release) and for QA to do its tests.
  If QA has any modification to make, it should then make a dedicated branch.
- a classic release branch is done *after* the release to manage the hot fixes

But the main idea remains: if you clone a repository, you get by default the `main` branch (Cf. the [Git 2.28 (Q3 2020) `init.defaultBranch` configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62983443/6309)), and that should show you what is currently running in production, allowing you to start debugging/fixing quickly.

See also [gitworkflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53405887/6309) to manage those branches.

Comment: Thanks Vonc. I had a same idea and communicated to the team but no one accepting here... frustrated...!!

Comment: @BalaVaradarajan yes, my proposition is a bit similar to http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/. But I would be interesting in the reason for the team's refusal.

Comment: first thank you for this answer, looks like this days master is not the default branch and all moved to main, I think you should consider it in the answer.

Comment: @talsibony Good point. I have updated this 8 years-old answer, also adding the new `init.defaultBranch` setting.