# How can I create a Git repository with the default branch name other than "master"?

Tags: git, version-control

In the [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches), it says

> “origin” is not special
>
> Just like the branch name “master” does not have any special meaning in Git, neither does “origin”. **While “master” is the default name for a starting branch when you run git init which is the only reason it’s widely used**, “origin” is the default name for a remote when you run git clone. If you run git clone -o booyah instead, then you will have booyah/master as your default remote branch.

That means, we can use our default branch name as *main* or *main-branch* or something like that. I didn't see any option in `man git-init` which will initialize my `repo` with a different default branch name.

[GitHub shows how to set the default branch name](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/) in its settings page. But I am not talking about how to set it on any specific *Git hosting site*. I am strictly asking in terms of Git only, not in regards to any specific *Git hosting site*.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Some work has been started to look at the naming of the main / default branch in https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2674.

Answer (score 506, accepted):

### Newer Git, New Repo

Since git version 2.28.0 the `git init` command now takes a `--initial-branch` (or `-b` for short) parameter. These two commands create a new Git repo with a branch named "trunk", which always made more sense to me than "master" (master of what?):

```
git init --initial-branch=trunk
git init -b trunk
```

This is configurable with the `init.defaultBranch` setting. If I want all new repos to have "trunk" as the default branch:

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch trunk
```

### Older Git, New Repo

Some systems still have older Git installations. My Debian 10 server (Buster, the *current* stable version as of October 2020) comes with Git 2.20, which does not support the `-b` option. One option is to create the repository and then change the branch name. This technique works for normal (non-bare) repos:

```
git init
git checkout -b trunk
```

This creates a new repository with `trunk` as the current branch instead of `master`.  The branch `master` does not actually exist--the branches don't get created until they have at least one commit.  Until the branch gets created, the branch only exists in `.git/HEAD`, which explains why the `master` branch will disappear when you switch to `trunk`.

### Bare Repos

For bare repos, you cannot run `git checkout` (that's what it means to be bare). Instead, you can change HEAD to point at a different branch:

```
git init --bare
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/trunk
```

### Old Repos

If you've already committed, you can run `git branch -m` instead:

```
git init
touch file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -m 'commit 1'
git branch -m trunk
```

This renames the branch from `master` to `trunk` once it's created.

This does seem a bit clunky since the mechanism is different depending on whether the repository is empty, but it works. You can also approach it as "creating a new branch and deleting `master`".

Comment: In the first case when you run `git checkout -b trunk`. Does that mean, from then on the default branch is trunk ?

Comment: "Default" is a bit of a misnomer.  "Current branch" is really what's going on here.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/ talks about the default branch, so I got little confused. I did little bit of experiment of what you said. turns out there is nothing like "Default" in git. thanks

Comment: That looks like a GitHub concept, not a Git concept.  It talks about pull requests, and in Git there is no such thing as a "pull request".

Comment: I was just looking for something like this

Comment: how to change master to trunk for a bare git repo created by `git --git-dir=/path/to/remote_main.git init --bare`?

Comment: @halfmoonhalf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301956/git-correct-way-to-change-active-branch-in-a-bare-repository

Comment: This is useful after the change from "master" to "main" default branch. Git command in WSL2 (git v2.25.1) still had master as default. So I needed to init and then checkout to main to do not have two branches.

Comment: @MarkusZeller: As far as I know "master" is still default in Git. Git is not the same thing as GitHub--it is GitHub which is changing the defaults.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Installing latest git for Windows already has "main" as (optional) default. 
 [main as default option](https://i.ibb.co/qjwGYNX/image.png).

Comment: @MarkusZeller: Exactly--"master" is still the default. If you don't like the default, you can configure it to be something else.

Comment: @DietrichEpp But Github makes "main" as default per se, and if you cloned or added the remote origin, that's nasty. That's why I commented to help others coming up with the same "problem". No critics on your answer, just a big thumb up. I am pretty sure, git will follow soon - as it is already prepared, because others like BitBucket, Gitlab or GitTower will do so, too.

Comment: Changing the HEAD in a newly-initiated bare repo seems to have no effect on which branch is checked out when cloning it (testing on v`2.25.1`). I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896894/what-determines-default-branch-when-cloning-from-git-bare-repository), which states that v`1.8.4.3` should have fixed it, so I'm still confused.

Comment: To be clear, I ran these commands: `mkdir repo; cd repo; git init --bare; git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/main; mkdir ../working; cd ../working; git clone ../repo; cd repo; cat .git/HEAD;` and the last line of the output was `ref: refs/heads/master`.

Comment: @jsejcksn: I think the problem here is that Git doesn’t get the right HEAD if you clone an empty repository. However, HEAD is still correctly changed in the bare repo… once the bare repo is not empty, or more specifically, once the default branch has commits in the bare repo, it will clone correctly with the correct default branch.

Comment: @DietrichEpp So is there a way to clone a newly-initialized (without any commits), bare repo and get the right HEAD?

Comment: @jsejcksn: Yes: run `git switch -c <branch>` after cloning.

Comment: @jsejcksn: If that doesn’t work for you, the other main option is to make changes to Git so it works the way you want.

Answer (score 93):

You can, indirectly, configure `git init` to use a different default branch: the current branch is defined by `HEAD`, which is “just” a textfile telling Git which ref is the current one.

Using `init.templateDir`, you can ask `git init` to use a different one:

```
# ~/.config/git/config or ~/.gitconfig
[init]
    templateDir = ~/.config/git/template/
```

and in `~/.config/git/template/HEAD`, put a single line (+ linebreak): `ref: refs/heads/main` (to default to branch `main`).

The whole contents of `templateDir` are copied to the `.git` directory when creating a repository; the default (here `/usr/share/git-core/templates`) contains some sample hooks and other files, but you can use your new template directory to setup default hooks, for example.

```
$ tree /usr/share/git-core/templates
/usr/share/git-core/templates
├── branches
├── description
├── hooks
│   ├── applypatch-msg.sample
│   ├── commit-msg.sample
│   ├── fsmonitor-watchman.sample
│   ├── post-update.sample
│   ├── pre-applypatch.sample
│   ├── pre-commit.sample
│   ├── prepare-commit-msg.sample
│   ├── pre-push.sample
│   ├── pre-rebase.sample
│   ├── pre-receive.sample
│   └── update.sample
└── info
    └── exclude

3 directories, 13 files
```

Comment: FYI for anyone following these instructions on OSX you might have to look in /usr/local/git/share/git-core/templates for the template files

Comment: NB: You can also create a `HEAD` file in the default template, though it'll tell you you're "reinitializing" a repository when you're actually creating one.

Answer (score 43):

Since **Git 2.28** (released July 27, 2020) a new configuration option, `init.defaultBranch` is being introduced to replace the hard-coded term `master`.

Default remains to `master`!

The user can override the default value of the configuration variable with:

```
$ git config --global init.defaultBranch main
```

Read the git doc chapter for further details [Introducing init.defaultBranch](https://github.blog/2020-07-27-highlights-from-git-2-28/#introducing-init-defaultbranch)

Comment: Yes, that is what I have written in my answer on that same page. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62983443/6309

Comment: And that is what I twitted, referring to that same answer: https://twitter.com/VonC_/status/1284968817010016268

Answer (score 29):

> How can I create a Git repository with the default branch name other than "`master`"?

You would use Git 2.28 (Q3 2020): the name of the primary branch in existing repositories, and the default name used for the first branch in newly created repositories, is made configurable, so that we can eventually wean ourselves off of the hardcoded '`master`'.

And reminder from [Aug. 2020 from **GitHub**](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-08-26-set-the-default-branch-for-newly-created-repositories/):

> **On October 1, 2020, if you haven't changed the default branch for new repositories for your user, organization, or enterprise, it will automatically change from `master` to `main`**.
> You can opt out of this change at any time:
>
> - For users, on the https://github.com/settings/repositories page
> - For organization owners, on the `https://github.com/organizations/YOUR-ORGANIZATION/settings/repository-defaults` page
> - For enterprise administrators, on the `https://github.com/enterprises/YOUR-ENTERPRISE/settings/member_privileges` page
>
> This change is one of many changes GitHub is making to support projects and maintainers that want to rename their default branch.
> To learn more about the changes we're making, see [github/renaming](https://github.com/github/renaming/).

But back to Git itself: (2.28, Q3 2020)
See [commit 508fd8e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/508fd8e8baf3e18ee40b2cf0b8899188a8506d07) (29 Jun 2020) by [Đoàn Trần Công Danh (`sgn`)](https://github.com/sgn).
See [commit 0068f21](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0068f2116e67fac511941442cbbf7b0109adf57a), [commit a471214](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a471214bd610bb415a37d5b2c3506b83549acd57), [commit 0cc1b47](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cc1b475bbcc530c5429c741fbcfdc2730d27223), [commit 32ba12d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32ba12dab2acf1ad11836a627956d1473f6b851a), [commit 6069ecc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6069eccdc9d6351f1668b85551bbee4b6ca7cbb0), [commit f0a96e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0a96e8d4c98c2394dc726b57b914f95cbc7a0de), [commit 4d04658](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d04658d8b5c72d2ebbb3aec7b06228e2ae1d327) (24 Jun 2020), and [commit 489947c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/489947cee5095b168cbac111ff7bd1eadbbd90dd) (23 Jun 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
See [commit 8747ebb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8747ebb7cde9e90d20794c06e6806f75cd540142) (24 Jun 2020) by [Don Goodman-Wilson (`DEGoodmanWilson`)](https://github.com/DEGoodmanWilson).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 11cbda2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11cbda2add5d3eb7c415f1f6dd8186181a7f9874), 06 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`init`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32ba12dab2acf1ad11836a627956d1473f6b851a): allow specifying the initial branch name for the new repository
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> There is a growing number of projects and companies desiring to change the main branch name of their repositories (see e.g. [Mislav Marohnić's tweet](https://twitter.com/mislav/status/1270388510684598272) for background on this).
>
> To change that branch name for new repositories, currently the only way to do that automatically is by copying all of Git's template directory, then hard-coding the desired default branch name into the `.git/HEAD` file, and then configuring `init.templateDir` to point to those copied template files.
>
> To make this process much less cumbersome, let's introduce a new option: `--initial-branch=<branch-name>`.

```
git init --initial-branch=hello myLocalRepo
# or
git config --global init.defaultBranch hello
git init myLocalRepo
```

And:

> ### [`init`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8747ebb7cde9e90d20794c06e6806f75cd540142): allow setting the default for the initial branch name via the config
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Don Goodman-Wilson</sup>

> We just introduced the command-line option `--initial-branch=<branch-name>` to allow initializing a new repository with a different initial branch than the hard-coded one.
>
> To allow users to override the initial branch name more permanently (i.e. without having to specify the name manually for each and every `git init` invocation), let's introduce the `init.defaultBranch` config setting.

Note: [commit 489947c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/489947cee5095b168cbac111ff7bd1eadbbd90dd), about the merge commit message, has since been reverted in Git 2.29, see "[how can I customize git's merge commit message?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63331954/6309)".
The `init.defaultBranch` setting remains.

---

This impacts submodules:

> ### [`submodule`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0a96e8d4c98c2394dc726b57b914f95cbc7a0de): fall back to remote's HEAD for missing remote..branch
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Philippe Blain</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> When `remote.<name>.branch` is not configured, [`git submodule update`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) currently falls back to using the branch name `master`.
> A much better idea, however, is to use the remote `HEAD`: on all Git servers running reasonably recent Git versions, the symref `HEAD` points to the main branch.
>
> Note: t7419 demonstrates that there *might* be use cases out there that *expect* [`git submodule update --remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)  to update submodules to the remote `master` branch even if the remote `HEAD` points to another branch.
> Arguably, this patch makes the behavior more intuitive, but there is a slight possibility that this might cause regressions in obscure setups.
>
> Even so, it should be okay to fix this behavior without anything like a longer transition period:
>
> - The [`git submodule update --remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) command is not really common.
> - Current Git's behavior when running this command is outright confusing, unless the remote repository's current branch *is* `master` (in which case the proposed behavior matches the old behavior).
> - If a user encounters a regression due to the changed behavior, the fix is actually trivial: setting `submodule.<name>.branch` to `master` will reinstate the old behavior.

---

Note that, with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), tests in `contrib/` are adjusted to the recent change to `fmt-merge-msg`.

See [commit b87528c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b87528c4d7b0a28430da405f8f4b18f2fb8b953b) (03 Aug 2020) by [Emily Shaffer (`nasamuffin`)](https://github.com/nasamuffin).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 83b8250](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83b8250904d3c5e6107a70c27759e91160e139b0), 10 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`Revert "contrib`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b87528c4d7b0a28430da405f8f4b18f2fb8b953b): `subtree`: adjust test to change in `fmt-merge-msg`"
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Emily Shaffer</sup>

> This reverts [commit 508fd8e8baf3e18ee40b2cf0b8899188a8506d07](https://github.com/git/git/commit/508fd8e8baf3e18ee40b2cf0b8899188a8506d07).
>
> In [6e6029a8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e6029a82acdb3d785eef15dc798f4d86c4ea445) (`fmt-merge-msg`: allow merge destination to be omitted again) we get back the behavior where merges against '`master`', by default, do not include "`into 'master'`" at the end of the merge message. This test fix is no longer needed.

Also:

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), update the tests to drop word '`master`' from them.

See [commit f33f2d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f33f2d3d54c12462701ea01e81da45e63e2c3087), [commit b6211b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6211b89eb3aee35afdcb1788869b5cf4b04a850) (26 Sep 2020), and [commit 432f5e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/432f5e638d00fc9175594c73c1a9e81af1928872), [commit 5a0c32b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a0c32bd4bfdf6e7c1d6f7049b41965b7e9e85d3), [commit 659288c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/659288cd9193a97d5f08c6ac090d58dfbdf6b345) (21 Sep 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 58138d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/58138d3f266569f945a7abc86fc897111c47640f), 05 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`tests`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6211b89eb3aee35afdcb1788869b5cf4b04a850): avoid variations of the `master` branch name
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> The term `master` has a loaded history that serves as a constant reminder of racial injustice. The Git project has no desire to perpetuate this and already started avoiding it.
>
> The test suite uses variations of this name for branches other than the default one. Apart from t3200, where we just addressed this in the previous commit, those instances can be renamed in an automated manner because they do not require any changes outside of the test script, so let's do that.
>
> Seeing as the touched branches have very little (if anything) to do with the default branch, we choose to use a completely separate naming scheme: `topic_<number>` (it cannot be `topic-<number>` because t5515 uses the `test_oid` machinery with the term, and that machinery uses shell variables internally, whose names cannot contain dashes).
>
> This trick was performed by this (GNU) sed invocation:
>
> ```
> $ sed -i 's/master\([a-z0-9]\)/topic_\1/g' t/t*.sh
> ```

And, still with Git 2.29:

See [commit 538228e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/538228ed23a1d5e17e89bb17086d4dda51325bd8), [commit a15ad5d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a15ad5d1bc23f3a6842360df5ee840b1dc3e4888) (08 Oct 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 62564ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62564ba4e5191aeb849266e8a1bb2845eb257baf), 08 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`t1415`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a15ad5d1bc23f3a6842360df5ee840b1dc3e4888): avoid using `main` as ref name
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> In preparation for a patch series that will change the fall-back for `init.defaultBranch` to `main`, let's not use `main` as ref name in this test script.
>
> Otherwise, the [`git for-each-ref ... | grep main`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a15ad5d1bc23f3a6842360df5ee840b1dc3e4888/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref))</sup> which wants to catch those refs would also unexpectedly catch `refs/heads/main`.
>
> Since the refs in question are worktree-local ones (i.e. each worktree has their own, just like `HEAD`), and since the test case already uses a secondary worktree called "`second`", let's use the name "`first`" for those refs instead.
>
> While at it, adjust the test titles that talk about a "repo" when they meant a "worktree" instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Azure Devops:

1. Under your project repo, select Branches.
2. On the Branches page, select More options next to the new default branch you want, and choose Set as default branch.

[image]

3. After you set the new default branch, you can delete the previous default if you want.