# How to set the default branch in Git bare repository?

Tags: git, repository, git-branch

When creating the master base repository from a workspace I made a mistake that I realized only significant time later:

The default branch is not `master`, but some merge branch like `post-merge`.
So I want the default branch to be `master` instead, but I don't know how to do that:

In a workspace I would simply `git checkout master`, then delete the other branch.
But obviously in a bare repository I cannot `checkout`.

Comment: Do you mean `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/trunk`, or do you mean `git config --global init.defaultBranch main`?

Comment: From the linked question - _"For bare repos, you cannot run git checkout (that's what it means to be bare). Instead, you can change HEAD to point at a different branch: `git init --bare; git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/trunk`"_

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand: Doesn't `git init` create a new repository? My repository exists already. So I guess I only need the second command.

Comment: Yes. Take from the answer what you need. You don't need `git init --bare` if you already have a repo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42871542/6607497 is specifically on creating a new repository, while my question is for an existing repository. I'd like to be able to provide an answer here, but I cannot as the question is closed now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42871621/989920 answers this question. `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/new-default-branch-name` will do what you want. Just make sure the branch `new-default-branch-name` already exists.

Comment: OK, fixed my problem, but stil lI think providing a specific answer to this question would be a good thing. I see other questions having 80% duplicate answers (that is most answers say practically the same) that are not deleted, but this is not accepted to be a valid question.

Comment: If SO allowed that, then we'd have millions of "how to format date in JS" questions, because they're all _slightly_ different.

Comment: No, because the title has a correct summary. There's a fundamental difference between "create a new git branch with a different name" and "Make an existing branch the default branch", even when an answer to one question will help to answer a *different* question, too.

Comment: I think we'll have to agree to disagree on that. I'm also not the only one who thinks this since the question was closed. I still believe this question is answered by the linked one.