# Git clone return master as default branch

Tags: git

When cloning a repository from a git server I'm getting master as the default branch, when the content of the `HEAD` file is `ref: refs/heads/main`.
If I clone the repo from the bare repository stored in my local machine, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion, the [OP Martin Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14196101/martin-daniel) finds out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72797562/git-clone-return-master-as-default-branch/72797703#comment128585645_72797703) the repository needs to be cloned with the **[git protocol 2](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f5cdbe485f5c560eb53734a2b25309409786b636/Documentation/technical/protocol-v2.txt)** in order to have the proper default branch set in the local cloned repository.

```
git config --global protocol.version 2
git clone ...
```

That derives from the [git protocol, which include a `symref` parameter](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f5cdbe485f5c560eb53734a2b25309409786b636/Documentation/technical/protocol-capabilities.txt#L194-L206=)

> This parameterized capability is used to inform the receiver which symbolic ref points to which ref;
>
> For example, "`symref=HEAD:refs/heads/master`" tells the
> receiver that `HEAD` points to `master`.
> This capability can be repeated to represent multiple `symref`s.
>
> Servers SHOULD include this capability for the `HEAD` `symref` if it is one of the refs being sent.
>
> Clients MAY use the parameters from this capability to select the proper initial branch when cloning a repository.

As noted in "[How does Git's transfer protocol work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50273976/6309)", and [commit 533e088](https://github.com/git/git/commit/533e088250cf4e8aad3143586850d7a89ed30571) from Git 2.22.1 (Q2 2019)

> The symref advertisement moved in v2 to be a part of the **[`ls-refs` command](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f5cdbe485f5c560eb53734a2b25309409786b636/Documentation/technical/protocol-v2.txt#L173-L202=)**.

Before 2.22.1, the server side support for "`git fetch`" used to show incorrect value for the HEAD symbolic ref when the namespace feature is in use.

---

Original answer:

It depends on the Git server version.

The `git config --global init.defaultBranch main` dates from [Git 2.28 (Q3 2020)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62983443/6309)

Before that, the [Git init default template](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory) would list `master` as its default branch.

> If I clone the repo from the bare repository stored in my local machine, everything works fine.

On a local machine, chances are your Git version is more recent than the one used on a server (On my RHEL 7.9 server, it is still a Git 1.8.5 from 2013!)

Comment: The server also runs on my machine, the only difference is that when I clone directly from the bare repo it doesn't go through an HTTP request.
By the way, I'm using Git 2.36.1

Comment: @MartinDaniel I suppose that your server on the same machine is also using 2.36.1?

Comment: yes I am using the same

Comment: @MartinDaniel OK. Would `git remote set-head origin main` be enough?

Comment: No, I ran the command and the result was `error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/main`

Comment: @MartinDaniel DOes your remote repository (the one on server) include a `main` branch? `git ls-remote` will show you the remote branches. `git branch -avv` will list the fetched remote branches. If in both cases there is no `main` branch... that would explain why cloning your remote repo result in `master` as the default branch.

Comment: Yes it had the branch main, it was actually initialized with it `git init -b main --bare` was the command, then set the default branch to be main executing `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/main`. Finally, the answer was that the server needed to be executing the clone commands using the git protocol 2. Thanks for all the precious answers!

Comment: @MartinDaniel Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.