# git not showing added files to staging area or committing files to repo

Tags: git, github

**edited

I'm trying to commit a file to my repo after making some changes- I initially uploaded the files to the repo directly through github.

```
C:\Users\me\repos\grow-my-day>git add popup.js

C:\Users\me\repos\grow-my-day>git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

C:\Users\me\repos\grow-my-day>git commit -m "Edit popup.js"
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

C:\Users\me\repos\grow-my-day>git push
Everything up-to-date
```

when I run `git log` I see that it's saying the last change was made on July 3rd which was the initial commit.

Comment: It's acting as if `popup.js` didn't change.

Comment: @jthill yeah, I figured. I still want to add the updated file to my repo though and I'm not sure what else to do

Comment: That's the thing: Git's telling you it hasn't changed, it's not updated.

Comment: @jthill is there any way to override that? I changed the files after I uploaded them directly through github and created a clone on my local machine after the fact so that's probably the reason I'm having this issue

Comment: Try `git add -f popup.js`. Newer Git versions tell you when `git add` bypasses an explicitly-added ignored file, as I recall it used to just, you know, ignore them. It's really not clear what you're doing here, what's going on, also try `git diff @ -- popup.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both messages, a `git status` would be helpful:

- one for realizing there is nothing to add and commit
- one for checking your current branch, which might be `main` by default, and no longer `master` (since [Aug. 2020 for GitHub repositories](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-08-26-set-the-default-branch-for-newly-created-repositories/), for instance)
  See [Git 2.28+ (Q3 2020)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62983443/6309) and the [`init.defaultBranch` setting](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-initdefaultBranch).

So:

```
git push -u origin main
```

Note that with the recent (Q3 2022) Git 2.37, and its new [`git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401899/6309), a simple `git push` would be enough.

But with the status `Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.`, there is nothing to push anyway.

If the file is not present at all on the remote side, check if it is ignored locally.

```
git check-ignore -v -- popup.js
```

Comment: yeah you're right my current branch was main.. I got confused looking at other stackoverflow answers to similar questions. ``git push -u origin main`` works but the file is not updated on git

Comment: @Lulu I have edited the answer to suggest checking if your file is ignored locally.

Comment: hmm, I get no output when I check if the file is being ignored

Comment: @Lulu So it is *not* ignored. Do you see it on the GitHub side? With its content up-to-date?

Comment: yeah it's on my github because the initial commit was through upload on the github website, but the content is not up to date. I think uploading the files through github directly and then creating a clone of the repo after the fact may be creating the issue